# fetching data oustide the map function using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, nodes

```js
let object = [
  {
    id: '01',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'maths',
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'science',
  },
  {
    id: '04',
    name: 'language',
    'Data.type': 'node',
  },
  {
    id: '05',
    name: 'language',
    'Data.type': 'node',
  }
  /*...*/
];

let type=[];
let result=[];
object.map(async (value) => {
  type.push(value["Data.type"]);
  if(some condition){
  // 1st condition
   if(some condition){
    // 2nd condition
     if(some condition){
      let path= await functionName();
      // 3rd conditon
      if(some condtion){
      // 4th condition
      result.push("task");
     }
    }
   }
  }
  // I can fetch result till here console.log(result)
});
// i can't fetch result here and i can't put condtion here as data present inside dObject is dummy for refrence purpose only
console.log(type);
console.log(result);
```

I declare two array outside the map function i can fetch name array easily but can't fetch result array i don't know why but its scope get ended inside the map function is there any other way i can fetch result outside the map function

- for reference i am posting my name function which work fine

```js
let object = [
  {
    id: '01',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'maths',
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'science',
  },
  {
    id: '04',
    name: 'language',
    'Data.type': 'node',
  },
  {
    id: '05',
    name: 'language',
    'Data.type': 'node',
  }
];

let type=[];
let result=[];
object.map(async (value) => {
  type.push(value["Data.type"]);
});
// i can't fetch result here and i can't put condtion here as data present inside dObject is dummy for refrence purpose only
console.log(type);
console.log(result);
```

here i can fetch my type array which i have declare perfectly but in 1st snippet i can't fetch result outside the map function

- as i wrote my condition perfectly that's why its running perfectly inside map function but not outside the map function

Comment: Try using var instead of let. Because var is function scoped and let is block scoped.

Comment: If you're using asynchronous code inside the loop (which I'm guessing you are), then please show the ACTUAL asynchronous code because that would be a major part of the issue.

Comment: yes there is `object.map(async (value)=>{ //rest code here});` @jfriend00 i am doing like this

Comment: Snippet 1 and snippet 2 looks the same to me (except all of the conditions in snippet 1.) What is the difference?

Comment: @jfriend00 i have updated my snippet i have used async await function inside the map function

Comment: Well `.map()` is NOT async aware.  It doesn't pause the loop to wait for your `await` so you end up trying to use the array BEFORE anything has been pushed into it.  You can either use `await Promise.all()` on the resulting array of promises that your `.map()` returns or you can switch to a `for` loop which IS `async` aware and will pause the loop for your `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `.map()` is NOT async aware.  It doesn't pause the loop to wait for your `await` so you end up trying to use the array BEFORE anything has been pushed into it by your asynchronous operations.  This is a timing issue.

You can either use `await Promise.all()` on the resulting array of promises that your `.map()` returns or you can switch to a `for` loop which IS `async` aware and will pause the loop for your `await`.

FYI, you should never use `.map()` if you're not interested in the resulting array that it returns as that's its entire point.  There are more efficient ways to just iterate an array.  And, when doing asynchronous things, a plain `for` loop is far, far, far more powerful these days with `await` since you get full control over the loop which `.forEach()` and `.map()` do not offer since they are not `async` aware.

You don't show much real code, but this would be the general idea with a `for` loop:

```
async someFunction() {

    let type=[];
    let result=[];
    for (let value of object) {
      type.push(value["Data.type"]);
      if(some condition){
      // 1st condition
       if(some condition){
        // 2nd condition
         if(some condition){
          let path= await functionName();
          // 3rd conditon
          if(some condtion){
          // 4th condition
          result.push("task");
         }
        }
       }
      }
    }
    console.log(result);
}

someFunction().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: as i am using `let path = await functionName()` in side `for (let value of object) {}` its showing me await only valid with async function

Comment: @Vikas - Yes, the parent function needs to be `async`.  That's the same for any function you use `await` in.  You don't show that function.  If there isn't a parent function, then you just need to put this code in an `async` function and then call it.

Comment: yes got it where i was doing mistake thank you @jfriend00

Comment: just for curiosity how will code look like if i am using `await Promise.all()` do i have to write like this `let path =await Promise.all(functionName());` ?

Comment: @Vikas - It depends upon your real code, but `await Promise.all(object.map(async value => {...}))` would tell you when all the iterations of the loop were done.  If you actually return a value from the `.map()` callback, then you can accumulate the values directly and in order with `let results = await Promise.all(object.map(async value => {... return someValue;}))`.  This will attempt to run all your asynchronous operations in parallel (which has pros and cons).